# Error connection to CVS

Tags: eclipse, ssl, proxy, connection, cvs

I try to connect to CVS through eclipse. After entering (host, repository path, user, password) and by clicking finish, it gives me the following error :

> Error validating location : "Could not connect to :pserver:username@host:/CVS/Myproject:I/O exception occured: ProxyHTTP: java.IOEXCEPTION: proxy error (the specified socket layer (SSL) port is not allowed.ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL REQUEST FROM THIS PORT. most web browser use port 443for SSL request .)"

What could I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously a problem with your proxy server. Try disabling proxy settings in Eclipse or ask your system administrator to fix the proxy server configuration.

Comment: Thank you I disabled the proxy, that allowed me to access the CVN

Answer (score 3):

If you need to access the Web via a proxy server, but use an internal CVS server that shouldn't be accessed via the proxy, you can add the CVS server to Eclipse's *proxy bypass list*.

To do this, go to Windows→Preferences→General→Network Connections and click 'Add Host'. You'll likely want to use wildcards to specify all internal servers, e.g. `*.mycompany.com.au` or `163.189.*`.

Comment: Just for more information: for a cntlm proxy I was using I had to add an exception to the Eclipse proxy configuration even though an exception already existed in the cntlm proxy to get it to work. Apparently some part of how eclipse composes the url was not matching the existing exception in the cntlm proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case, i solved this issue going to: windows -> preferences -> network connections and set **Active Provider = Direct**

As soon as i modified this i was able to check out the code.